# Correct way to send data from the back-end to the front-end with webbapp2?

Tags: python, webapp2

I'm learning and I'm stuck with something I can't understand.

I have a simple hello world app built with python GAE and webbapp2.

I want to display a chart on the front-end using D3.js

If I'm able to display some data directly into the HTML section of my front-end (`<p>{{data}}</p>`) I'm not able to pass any data within the `<script> </script>` tag of my front-end.

Here is the `MainHandler` of my back-end :

```
MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        data = [{'Letter': 'A', 'Freq': 20  },{'Letter' : 'B','Freq': 12},{'Letter' : 'C','Freq': 47}]
        template_values = {
            'data' : data
        }
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', MainHandler),
], debug=True)
```

In the Front-end I have a simple `console.log({{data}})` which is causing the following error `Unexpected token &`

I guess there is something I don't understand here but I don't know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The templating engine is [escaping](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#html-escaping) your data, to prevent it from confusing the browser's rendering engine, or causing security issues.  So

`[{'Letter': 'A', 'Freq': 20  }]`

is rendered as

`[{&#39;Letter&#39;: &#39;A&#39;, &#39;Freq&#39;: 20}]`

or

`[{&#quot;Letter&#quot;: &#quot;A&#quot;, &#quot;Freq&#quot;: 20}]`

This is confusing `console.log`, which is a javascript function that doesn't know about html escaping.

You can override this behaviour in Jinja2 using the [safe](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#safe) filter.

`console.log({{ data|safe }})`

Note that you should only override escaping on trusted data.